# JavaScript/ExtendScript refresh at startup

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I'm working with Startup Scripts in InDesign.

I found that some changes are not applied because of some caching InDesign does.

I want to add a refresher/updater at the start of the script. If InDesign launches the cache get's cleared or something similar.

Any ideas on how to do this?
I tried `window.update();` but that failed. Window not defined error.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "cache". Which issues did you exactly face ?

Comment: Well I have a script in the "Start up" folder that runs as soon as InDesign is Launched. It creates a custom menu. However if I change something I need to start up with `Shift`, `crtl`, `alt`, `cmd`. Which resets your preferences and then it works. While writing this I might just change the name of the document.

Comment: Startup Scripts are run per session. They are loaded once and for all. Only way to "refresh" is actually to quit and relaunch. Otherwise, you may want not to use a startup script or use a secondary helper to change values on the fly like a side script or some settings file.